IText7: is CertIDBC.MatchesIssuer implementation correct?
IText7 dotnet.
Current implementation in CertIDBC:
public virtual bool MatchesIssuer(IX509Certificate issuerCert) {
    return new CertIDBC(
        certificateID.HashAlgorithm.Algorithm.Id, 
        issuerCert, 
        new BigIntegerBC(certificateID.SerialNumber.Value)
    ).GetCertID().Equals(certificateID);
}

Shouldn't it be:
public virtual bool MatchesIssuer(IX509Certificate issuerCert) {
    return new CertIDBC(
        certificateID.HashAlgorithm, 
        issuerCert, 
        new BigIntegerBC(certificateID.SerialNumber.Value)
    ).GetCertID().Equals(certificateID);
}

That appears to cause problems when checking for equality the two certs. Original certId (right side) doesnt have a parameters field, but certId created from issuer has. Maybe it's because CertIdBC constructor passes parameters field as DerNull.Instance into AlgorithmIdentifier constructor.
CertId created from issuer (left side)
Original certId (right side)
As far as I've seen Java implementation passes whole AlgorithmIdentifier not just it's id.
OCSP response

If we examine the Bouncy Castle implementation, we see that no algorithm parameters are foreseen.
The same goes when we look into the OCSP specification.

Updated my post by giving an example.

Can you add the complete ocsp response?

Updated original post

Sorry I mixed things up a little bit. Updated post again

"If we examine the Bouncy Castle implementation, we see that no algorithm parameters are foreseen." - When I follow your link, I see a class that stores the hash algorithm in a AlgorithmIdentifier which contains a mandatory OID DerObjectIdentifier and an optional parameters Asn1Encodable. Thus, parameters are possible but may also be dropped. The code @Linas refers to never drops the parameters field but assumes a DerNull instance. In the wild you will find both dropped parameters and NULL parameters.

On dropping parameters or using NULL: "There are two possible encodings for the AlgorithmIdentifier parameters field associated with these object identifiers.  The two alternatives arise from the loss of the OPTIONAL associated with the algorithm identifier parameters when the 1988 syntax for AlgorithmIdentifier was translated into the 1997 syntax.  Later the OPTIONAL was recovered via a defect report, but by then many people thought that algorithm parameters were mandatory.  Because of this history some implementations encode parameters as a NULL element while others omit them entirely."

For parameterless signature algorithms there usually is a rule whether parameters shall be dropped or whether they shall be set to NULL - see e.g. https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8301793 - but for plain hash algorithms you see both in the wild.

The two certs ids are semantically equal, yet it returns false.
Is there an issue with the library or not?

It is a shortcoming, and it will be handled. But we need to consider the two possibilities.
A ticket was created.

It's been fixed in the latest 9.1.0 snapshot version.
